# What causes this component to detect changes in its props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In the following minimal example, a parent component has a `data` property and passes `data.value` to a child. I am struggling to understand what exactly is going on here with the update strategy:

```
const MY_DATAVALUE = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

const DATA = {
  value: MY_DATAVALUE
};

function Child(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child props changed");
  }, [props]);

  return <h1>Child</h1>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(DATA);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data changed");
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data.value changed");
  }, [data.value]);

  function handleButtonClick() {
    const newData = {
      value: MY_DATAVALUE
    };
    setData(newData);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Button</button>
      <Child value={data.value} />
    </>
  );
}
```

(See this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-mendeleev-1q5rs))
Now, when the button is clicked, I think the following happens:

- App's `handleButtonClick()` is executed and the `data`-state now refers to a new object. Therefore App's first `useEffect` (checking for `data`) triggers.
- However `data.value` still contains the same reference (to `MY_DATAVALUE`), therefore App's second `useEffect` (checking for `data.value`) does not trigger.

BUT: The Child's `useEffect` (checking for `props`) triggers. Why is that? According to the parent, `data.value` did NOT change (Otherwise the second `useEffect` would have triggered).

Can you explain to me, why the Childs `useEffect` triggers`? How could I find out if the props "really" changed? Would I have to individually check for all prop-keys?
Thank you!

Comment: I think this is because the state of the `App` component is passed as a prop to the `Child` and the `App` component is re-rendered with the state update, therefore the children are re-rendered as well due to React not doing a "deep" compare of the object contents. I think you need to use `useReducer` for deep state object comparison.

Comment: `useMemo` and `useCallback` checks the diff of the props. use effect gets triggered on any change though it is the same data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` dependencies will trigger a change if what we provide is different. This happens if we pass the same reference with a different value or if we pass a different reference.

```
const newData = {
  value: MY_DATAVALUE
};

setData(newData);
```

`data` now refers to a different object, while the `value` key refers to the same as the previous value.

This means, this hook will trigger:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("data changed");
}, [data]);
```

While this will not trigger:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("data.value changed");
}, [data.value]);
```

---

So far this is what you explained in both points.

In the case of the child, the `props` object is a new reference on every render.

For this reason, this hook will always trigger:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("child props changed");
}, [props]);
```

While this hook would not trigger:

```
const MY_DATAVALUE = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

// In Parent...

<Child value={MY_DATAVALUE} />

// In Child...

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("child value changed");
}, [props.value]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. Especially the statement "the props object is a new reference on every render." made it clear for me! One minor thing:  "if we pass the same reference with a different value" means that we pass the same reference with a different `primitive` value, right?

Comment: @Raphael, You're welcome! Yes, that is what I meant, in the case of objects it gets confussing to talk about references and values. `{} === {}` will return false, while `const a = {}` `a === a` will return true; and in the case of `primitives` as you said `123 === 123` will return true.